# Making a web application scalable in terms of Database and requests

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, scalability

I have built a standalone web application. A user can hit the URL, and a rich text note editor will open and type in a note, save it, update it, and share it. It's written using the spring-boot framework with an embedded tomcat server. Currently, it's deployed on two different Linux boxes for redundancy so that if one service crashes, the other is there to take care of the requests.

I am looking for ways to make it more scalable. I am unsure how the service will behave when millions of users create notes. For storing the notes, I am using a MySQL database.

Apart from how the app handles millions of requests per second, is there any other scalability area I should be aware of?

A few things I can think of:

1. What happens when the data in the table grows large. There is only one table. For simplicity, let's assume it has the columns: id, user_id, and text. The id of the more, the user_id who created the note, and the note's text. Now a single user can create multiple notes, and millions of users can create several notes. Suppose the table entry in the table grows beyond 10^6. The machine on which the database is deployed is a separate box. And there is a network call for querying the table.
   The queries could be like: fetch the note with a particular id.
   Can we do better here with some different designs?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, but for the big data, look at partitioning (and perhaps rotating partitions). But a million rows is really no biggie. For scaling in general, Look at InnoDB Clusters. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-introduction.html. - simple fetches can come from read-only instances. For really big data, consider Cassandra rather than MySQL. Different optimizations for different purposes.

Comment: @Jerry When you say for very big data. How many rows are you looking at?
More than 10^9 or 10^12? Does Cassandra also maintain a similar table structure as MySQL?

Comment: The place where RDBMS's, and MySQL in particular, break is somewhere between 10^9 and 10^12, I think, depending on many variables. There are databases specifically built for masses of historical data ("historical" in the sense that once the data is written it will not be updated), and one of those is what you want. Cassandra and AWS Redshift (which is also Cassandra for all I know) are built for massive data that is generally static. You lose the JOIN syntax of a relational DB, but you only have one table, so already you're not playing to the strength of a RDBMS.